# Pycharm: 'from typing import list' inserted into file after 'Add type hint for variable my_list', followed by a warning

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Pycharm version information]

I'm using:

PyCharm 2022.1 (Community Edition)

Build #PC-221.5080.212,built on April 12, 2022

Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64

---

If I create a `list` variable (for example):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Pycharm prompts me to '**Add type hint for variable my_list**'.

So I click, and the variable now has a type hint:

```
my_list: list[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However, the type-hinted variable now has a yellow highlight box around it, and there is a warning in the 'problems' pane:
**Warning: Unused import statement 'from typing import List'**

I search the file for '**from typing import List**' and delete it and the warning (and highlight) goes away.

But I'm puzzled by this Pycharm behaviour.
Is '**from typing import List**' a bug?
Or is it required, and if so, what should I then do?

Comment: I think the bug in Pycharm is that it should use a capital l in list for the type hint, so it should be `List[int]`. However, adding a type hint isn't necessary here anyway, it doesn't add anything

Comment: At one point, `from typing import List` would have been required in order to write this type hint (and it would have to have been written `List[int]`).  But somewhere along the way, the ability to make constrained type hints was added directly to all the standard types, so you can now say `list[int]` without needing to import anything.

Comment: @Lecdi I know it's not necessary, it was just an example. My main concern was whether 'from typing import list' being written into the file indicated a bug or a call to action on my part.

Comment: @jasonharper So would you agree that 'from typing import list' is indeed a Pycharm bug?